# FPDF does not paint the results of my query

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm generating several pdf, one of them is by date range, in which only the header of the pages is painted but not the data and it doesn't give me an error.  I am also concatenating the dates as subtitle of the pages of my pdf but it only prints the words from and to. So I am super confused with this problem, thanks for reading.

PHP

```
<?php 
require "../../plugins/fpdf185/fpdf.php";
include "../../modelo/conexionPDO.php";
$fincio = (isset($_POST['fechaI'])) ? $_POST['fechaI'] : '';
$ffinal = (isset($_POST['fechaF'])) ? $_POST['fechaF'] : '';
class PDF extends FPDF { 
        // Cabecera de página
        function Header()
        {
        // Logo
        $this->Image('../../img/logo_pdf.png',10,5,80);
        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',30);
        // Movernos a la derecha
        $this->Cell(710);
        // Título
        $this->Cell(70,10,'Inventory of Operating Assets',0,1,'C');
       /*$this->Cell(70,10, $fe1,0,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(70,10, $fe2,0,0,'C');*/
        // Salto de línea
        $this->Ln(30);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
        $this->Cell(35,10, 'Fecha', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(200,10, utf8_decode('Clasificación'), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(20,10, 'Grupo', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(30,10, 'Sub-Grupo', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(30,10, utf8_decode('Sección'), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(35,10, 'Tipo de bien', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(100,10, 'Concepto Mov', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(15,10, 'Cant', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(30,10, utf8_decode('N°Bien'), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(50,10, utf8_decode('N°Control'), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(450,10, utf8_decode('Nombre/Descripción'), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(270,10, 'Departamento', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(20,10, 'Piso', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(40,10, 'Cod. Depart.', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(40,10, 'Valor Unitario', 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $this->Cell(30,10, 'Estatus', 1, 1, 'C', 0);
    }
    // Pie de página
    function Footer()
    {
    // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Número de página
    $this->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode('Página ').$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
    }
    $conPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $sql=$conPDO->prepare('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha, "%d-%m-%Y") AS fecha, nombre as clasificacion, grupo, subgrupo, seccion, tipo_de_bien, concepto, cantidad, n_bien, n_control, nombre_y_descripcion, departamentos as departamento, ubicacion as piso, codigo_depto, v_unitario, estado as estatus from bienes INNER JOIN clasificacion on bienes.clasificacion=clasificacion.id_clasi INNER JOIN concepto_mov on bienes.concep_mov=concepto_mov.codigo INNER JOIN departamentos on bienes.departamento=departamentos.id_depa INNER JOIN estatus on bienes.estatus=estatus.id_esta WHERE bienes.estatus=1 and fecha between ? and ?');
    $sql->bindParam(1, $fincio);
    $sql->bindParam(2, $ffinal);
    $sql->execute();
    $rows=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       $pdf = new PDF();
       $pdf->AliasNbPages();
       $pdf->AddPage('L', array(300,1420));
       $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',16);
       $pdf->SetY(20);
       $pdf->SetX(710);
       $pdf->Write(1, 'Since: '.$fincio. 'Until:' .$ffinal);
       foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $pdf->Cell(35,10, $row['fecha'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(200,10, utf8_decode($row['clasificacion']), 1, 0, '', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(20,10, $row['grupo'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10, $row['subgrupo'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10, $row['seccion'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(35,10, $row['tipo_de_bien'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(100,10, utf8_decode($row['concepto']), 1, 0, '', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(15,10, $row['cantidad'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10, $row['n_bien'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(50,10, utf8_decode($row['n_control']), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(450,10, $row['nombre_y_descripcion'], 1, 0, '', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(270,10, utf8_decode($row['departamento']), 1, 0, '', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(20,10, utf8_decode($row['piso']), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10, utf8_decode($row['codigo_depto']), 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10, $row['v_unitario'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10, $row['estatus'], 1, 1, 'C', 0);
        };
        $pdf->Output();
 ?>

//JS
let $inputFechaInicial=d.querySelector('#f-incio').value,
    $inputFechaFinal=d.querySelector('#f-final').value;
                    
if ($inputFechaInicial.match(/^(\d{1,2})[-](\d{1,2})[-](\d{3,4})$/) || $inputFechaFinal.match(/^(\d{1,2})[-](\d{1,2})[-](\d{3,4})$/)) {
    d.querySelector('span#f-incio').classList.remove('is-active');
    d.querySelector('span#f-final').classList.remove('is-active');
    $inputFechaInicial=$inputFechaInicial.split('-').reverse().join('-');
    $inputFechaFinal=$inputFechaFinal.split('-').reverse().join('-');
    let op= new FormData();
    op.append('fechaI', $inputFechaInicial);
    op.append('fechaF', $inputFechaFinal);
    fetch('./reportes/operativos/fechas.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body:op
    })
    .then(res=>{return res.ok ?(res.json()) :Promise.reject(res);})
    .catch(err=>{})
    finally(()=>{})
    window.open('./reportes/operativos/fechas.php');
```

I have already tried with var_dump($_POST) if receiving data and the query is well done because I have the same query in another section where I get the same data but I paint it in a Datatable.